# Although I have JAVA_Home set, the system can not find it

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu-18.04, java-home

I set my JAVA_HOME variable the follow path: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk11 and when i put the following comand: java -version , it shows me the current version and echo $JAVA_HOME indicates the above path.
When I start tomcat the following error message comes up:
neither JAVA_HOME nor JRE_HOME variable defined.

I setting up everything right, but the tomcat cant find it.

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat calls a script, setenv.sh, from catalina.sh.

Create a script called setenv.sh in the directory CATALINA_BASE/bin, and add the line: "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk11". Make the script executable, i.e. chmod +x setenv.sh

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the following line in your .bashrc file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

The .bashrc file is located in the /home directory.